# Running 10 functions asynchronously in Djano Views using Asyncio

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Im facing difficulties while trying to execute around **10 functions simultaneously using asyncio** in Django. I could not find nay clear documentation on how to use **asyncio with django**.

I made around 10 http requests to different using TOR which is by default slow. Instead of making these requests one by one, which usually takes around 2 minutes, I wanted to perform all the 10 requests simultaneously. There are 10 distinct functions each making a http request a different URL and scrape data and return JSON.

**URLscrape.py** :

```
async def scrape1(username):
    response = request.get('http://example.com'+username)
    return response.json()

async def scrape2(username):
    response = request.get('http://something.com'+username)
    return response.json()
```

I have 10 individual functions like the above with different URLs and perfrom scraping and return a json data. In Django views, I did like this:

**Views.py**

```
from URLscrape import scrape1, scrape2........scrape10

def scrapper():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    feature1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, scrape1, username)
    feature2 = loop.run_in_executor(None, scrape2, username)
    ....
    feature10 = loop.run_in_executor(None, scrape10, username)

    response1 = await future1
    response2 = await future2 
    .....
    response10 = await future10
 
    response1 = response1.text
    ......
    response10 = response2.text
  
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'scrape1':response1,'scrape10':response10})
```

But I dont know how to use **loop.run_until_complete()** to complete the script. Im in a restricted situation to use 10 individual functions for **scraping**. Im want to run the 10 simultaneously but I dont know how. I could not understand the concept and syntax of asyncio. Please help!!!

Comment: You probably need to drop the awaits and get the responses with `response1, response2, ... = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(feature1, feature2, ...))`

Comment: Also, using asyncio just to run `requests` under `run_in_executor` doesn't bring you any of the benefits of asyncio, you're still running threads under the hood. I would recommend switching to an asyncio-aware http library such as `aiohttp`.